# Wordpress multisite - Get a users role from a different site on the network

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress multisite with two sites - a primary site and a child site.

I have two user roles - a standard (free) role, and a gold (paid) role.

Users can sign up to the primary site either as a standard or paid user but they cannot sign up to the child site.

Users sign up to the network and are given access to the whole network and create a blog post for which ever site they choose.

User roles are stored on the primary site and everyone is given a standard access to the child site - there is no gold access to the child site ... so a standard user would get standard access to the primary site and standard access to the child site, a gold user would be given gold access to the primary site and by default standard access to the child site.

With me so far? Right! So what I want to do is display / hide content on the child site based on the roles of the primary site.

So say a gold user creates a blog post on the child site, when users are viewing this from the front end I want to (simplified but you get the idea) display a banner that says 'I'm from a gold user!'

In the child theme in functions.php I've been able to detect the user type to hide content with this;

```
if ( !current_user_can('access_gold_user') ){
  // content that I want to hide
}
```

But this can only be used to detect the users privileges for the current site ... so is there anyway to adapt this to detect the primary sites user roles?

I feel like I could have explained this in an easier way but I'm not sure how ... so I hope that's all clear at the least!

If anyone can offer any advice on this or point me in the correct direction I'd be extremely grateful

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't access the user's roles in the way your question assumes/wants. Instead you have to check the global roles array for your user's role, like so:

```
$userData = get_userdata( $userId );
$userRoles = $userData->roles;

if ( in_array("access_gold_user", $userRoles) ) {
    // yay, user has this role
} else {
    // boo, user does not have this role
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: This seems like the way to go ... but I can only seem to return the data from the child blog at the moment with this

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out a solution to this one, here's how I did it ...

The parent blog has a blog_id of 1, so if you want to do something similar to this just change that 1 to whatever your parent blog ID is and you're good to go

```
$userData = get_userdata( $userId );
$userRoles = $userData->roles;

$get_users_obj = get_users(array( 
    'blog_id' => 1,
    'search' => get_current_user_id())
 ); $user_roles = $get_users_obj[0]->roles[0];

echo "The parent role is = ", $user_roles;
```